# Views block to list related taxonomy terms

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I'm trying to create a Views block which will list related taxonomy terms. To explain in a bit more detail:

Vocabulary is:

Fruits

-- Apple

-- Banana

-- Kiwi

When on a node tagged with Apple, I'd like the block to list terms Apple, Banana and Kiwi i.e. terms with the same parent.

Is this possible in Views? I've been trying to build the correct relationship/argument but not getting very far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

This module does the trick: http://drupal.org/project/views_arg_parent_term

Steve